# Is initrd.img (grub's "Loading initial ramdisk ...") slowing down my boot?

Tags: boot, grub2, initramfs, bootchart, defrag

I'm on an SSD where file fragmentation shouldn't matter that much anyway but I noticed "loading initial ramdisk ..." message in grub is taking longer that I think it should. It lasts about 7 seconds before Plymouth runs. Plymouth itself only takes about 3 seconds (it would be nice if it started sooner and lasted longer though). Then lightdm / greeter screen comes up over a 2 to 3 seconds.

So I did a little experimenting and ran `filefrag -v /boot/init*` and noticed my kernel 4.4.0-53 seems overly fragmented:

```
File size of /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic is 49027703 (11970 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..       3:    4351562..   4351565:      4:            
   1:        4..    4095:    2334720..   2338811:   4092:    4351566:
   2:     4096..    8191:    2330624..   2334719:   4096:    2338812:
   3:     8192..   10239:    2355200..   2357247:   2048:    2334720:
   4:    10240..   11969:    2408448..   2410177:   1730:    2357248: last,eof
```

I'm curious how a fragmented `initrd.img` will impact booting performance. Is it worth defragging?

Of course I'm always open to suggestions for making `initrd.img` smaller and faster as well.

**Note:** Besides the mSata SSD and full-size SSD my laptop has a full-size HDD that contains Ubuntu 14.04 so I'm interested in defragging `initrd.img` in general, not just for SSD. The current boot session is from the mSata SSD though which is limited to SATA II speeds unlike the full-size drives which are on SATA III bus.

### EDIT 1: - `systemd` Boot Chart

As per comments below I've included the *systemd-bootchart* which is generated by modifying grub kernel parameters with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash vt.handoff=7 kaslr init=/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart"
```

The boot chart is saved to: `/run/log/bootchart-20161224-1801.svg`. I had to use `gimp` to open and export it in `.jpg` format at 75% quality to make it fit in Ask Ubuntu's 2.1 MB limit. The exported file is shown below:

[image: systemd bootchart]

Notice the 9 second delay at the begining. The "normal" delay of 7 seconds for "Loading initial ramdisk ..." message in grub is now about 10 seconds. The extra time likely attributable to *systemd-bootchart* overhead.

### EDIT 2: RAM and cgroups

As per comments (requests) below `RAM` and `cgroups` from `/var/log/syslog` are included in this edit.

Output from `free -m`:

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7843        3167         820        1574        3854        2740
Swap:          7999           4        7995
```

Note that SWAP is only used for testing `OOM Killer` and can be erased. Indeed technically it shouldn't be on an SSD in the first place.

Output from `grep cgroup < /var/log/syslog.1`:

```
$ grep cgroup < /var/log/syslog.1
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.011642] Initializing cgroup subsys io
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.011645] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.011651] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.011653] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.011655] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.011657] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.011659] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.011662] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    0.011664] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
Dec 24 15:22:50 dell kernel: [    6.204710] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.010846] Initializing cgroup subsys io
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.010849] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.010855] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.010857] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.010860] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.010861] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.010864] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.010867] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    0.010868] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
Dec 24 15:23:33 dell kernel: [    7.338815] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.010844] Initializing cgroup subsys io
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.010847] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.010853] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.010855] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.010857] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.010859] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.010861] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.010864] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    0.010866] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
Dec 24 15:45:25 dell kernel: [    5.977461] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.010848] Initializing cgroup subsys io
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.010852] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.010858] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.010860] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.010862] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.010864] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.010866] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.010870] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    0.010871] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
Dec 24 16:09:31 dell kernel: [    6.663158] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.011644] Initializing cgroup subsys io
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.011647] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.011654] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.011656] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.011658] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.011660] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.011662] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.011665] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    0.011667] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
Dec 24 18:00:44 dell kernel: [    6.388658] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.010850] Initializing cgroup subsys io
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.010854] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.010860] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.010862] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.010864] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.010866] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.010868] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.010871] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
Dec 24 18:01:33 dell kernel: [    0.010873] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
Dec 24 18:01:34 dell kernel: [   12.036550] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
```

Note this log contains multiple boots.

### Edit 3 - Speed improved.

After implementing the Q&A answer I wrote  ([How can I set up a password for the 'rm' command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865023/how-can-i-set-up-a-password-for-the-rm-command)) where a wrapper script password protects the `rm` command, boot speed has doubled.

Here's the new graph:

[image: bootchart dec 30]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think defragging is your problem, but you could do this...

In `terminal`...

- type `man update-initramfs` # to learn more about this command.
- then type `sudo update-initramfs -c` # to create a new file from scratch.
- then type `reboot`

Comment: `update-initramfs` is run frequently, ie whenever a new kernel is installed.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm creating a new file, not updating an existing file... partially to address the OP's defrag concern... and maybe to speed things up.

Comment: The `-c` parameter by itself doesn't work on my system at least. I need to use: `sudo update-initramfs -c - k 'uname -r'` where the single quotes around `uname -r` are really back ticks.

Comment: Did it make any difference?

Comment: ps: are your disk partitions aligned? Use `sudo fdisk -l` for a quick test, or `sudo parted` for a more complete test.

Comment: As far as file fragmentation is concerned it took out 1 extent so there are now 4 instead of 5. As far as boot time is concerned I don't think so but it's subjective. For full defragging I think the utility `e4defrag` should be used but am not sure how much that will help.

Comment: `/dev/sdb3` partition isn't aligned but I'm booting off of `/dev/sdc3` and it along with `/dev/sda` have all partitions aligned.

Comment: maybe install `systemd-bootchart`?

Comment: I've added the bootchart. I'm thinking of renaming the question to "Why is initrd.img (loadiing initial ramdisk...) so slow?" as it likely has nothing to do with file fragmentation even if most users would want a defragged file.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the bootchart image is too small to be readable. ps: when you checked the partition alignment, did you use fdisk or parted? I'd recommend parted for a complete check for "optimal" alignment. And... how much RAM and swap do you have? Do you see any cgroup memory errors in syslog?

Comment: Can't you click on the image to zoom in? Partitions are aligned correctly on the disk in question `/dev/sdc`. Non-aligned extended partition is on a different disc that is unused and not mounted: `/dev/sdb`

Comment: I zoomed to the max. Not readable. See my last edit to my previous comment.

Comment: RAM and cgroups added.

Comment: There's a problem with your cgroups and your superblock.

Comment: That's interesting... I should check out the BIOS scsi vs achi again. At one time it was setup for Intel RST, maybe I didn't undo it all properly. Probably not but worth a shot. Other than that I'll have to do some reading up on `cgroups` and `superblocks` :D

Comment: You might just need to copy a backup superblock into the primary superblock?

Comment: I'll look at that later whilst turkey is roasting :)... In mean time +1 for your great advise to-date.