# How can I set up a password for the 'rm' command?

Tags: command-line, permissions, password, rm

My friends keep deleting my files using the terminal. So please help me out by explaining how to make a password for `rm` command.

Comment: You will want to password protect the user account so those "friends" don't access it in the first place.

Comment: You should really try to learn how the system works and use its functionality.

Comment: It's likely that your friends are trying to "teach you a lesson" by screwing around with your computer when you leave it unguarded.  Learn that lesson by protecting your account and disallowing guest access, or providing guest access with reduced permissions.

Comment: Please also remember about the `unlink` command. Also about the `mv` command, because you can effectively overwrite files with it. [Also...](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/43)

Comment: @aswin What if Your friends will use _root_ account?

Comment: With friends like these who needs enemies?

Comment: And then what will you do when they delete your files without using the terminal?

Comment: That's just peak. I don't mean to be mean or rude to you and your friends, but Bruv you need some new friends, because those guys are just horrible.

Comment: @kasperd: <WestWing>With friends like these, who needs anemonies?</WestWing>

Comment: You're trying to produce a technological solution to a social problem. This is doomed to failure.

Comment: It seems the OP abandoned this. It's not clear that if the OP's friend uses his own account or he has the OP's password (so that the OP wants need another password for `rm`) and whether the friend has root permission or not?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc a question which is 2 days old, in this time of the year I would not call abandoned, many of us have family to be with and all that. But yes it would be nice if the OP would show up and clarify his question.

Comment: I've yet to setup a `guest account` but I cab imagine a situation where I would do that for a `friend`. If the friend was perusing the net and linux commands I can see them stumbling across `rm` instructions. In this case a password to invoke it from the terminal is a good idea. A better question would have been how do I prevent access to terminal where there is a gnome answer for Ubuntu. That way it would prevent `mv`, `dd`, `gparted` and other commands a nubcake (AU chat phrase not my own) might use.

Comment: Blocking `rm` or password-protecting it is pointless. You block that, I'll use `find -delete`. You block `find` command, I'll use `python`. And when you block python, I'll use `C` or `Perl`, or whatever else available. And you can't block many of those tools, since OS relies on them, many apps rely on them. As long as there's access to computer altogether, there is 1001 ways to delete everything.  Get better friends and start taking your security seriously.

Answer (score 46):

There's no easy way to set up such a password on the `rm` command itself, not without a lot of code hacking that'll probably break things like `apt-get` installing packages and removing files, and making you have to enter the password a thousand times, or potentially disrupting access to the command to people who *would* need it (like you, to delete your own files).  You can sort of do this by having multiple user accounts and multiple access permission sets, and restricting access to different sections of data, such as your home directory so they can't get to it.

(The other option is individual user accounts for each users, and then Access Control Lists, as is detailed in the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/865027/10616) that was posted by [Videonauth](https://askubuntu.com/users/522934/videonauth))

Here's the core problem - you're letting your friends use your system.  This has ***numerous*** security implications - the concept of "anyone with physical access to the box is going to be able to control the system and do any tasks" is an IT Security Mantra, which is why you don't 'share' physical systems access except with trusted authorized personnel.

---

The only *truly* sane way to do this is to not give your friends access to *your* computer, and give them a 'dedicated "Guest" system' that they can use, that you don't really care about the files on as much.  This is the most 'secure' way to keep your files safe.

---

Of course, if that's not an option, then your only really safe option is to configure multiple user accounts, one for each user, with different home folders, and do not allow them access to your own home directory or access to any other user's home directories.  And then keep everything you don't want them touching in your home directory, and don't give them `sudo` access, the `root` password, or share your password with them.

This is how you'd do this:

Let's say my name is "Foo" and I want user "Bar", a friend, to use my system but not access my files.  The first step is to deny access to anyone but me to my home directory.  This is to permit other users to *not* delete your files, but to also prevent other users from snooping around in your home directory and seeing what types of stuff you've got in your home directory:

```
chmod 750 /home/Foo
```

The second step is to create a user account for "Bar" (do NOT type what's in parentheses below, it's for information purposes only).  This way, we can make sure he has his own separate set of access rights:

```
sudo adduser --create-home --user-group --shell /bin/bash Bar
sudo passwd Bar
(set a temporary password - you will not see characters as you type though)
```

The *third* step is to then restrict their home directory too so nobody can pry into their files either.  This is just making things equal.

```
sudo chmod 750 /home/Bar
```

Wash your hands, rinse them off well, then repeat these steps for however many users you have on the system.  They won't be able to access your files, and since you're not going to give them administrator privileges, they can't delete your files without attempting to `sudo` to do so - since you don't permit this, they can't touch your stuff.  And they won't be able to see your files either, without becoming superuser, which won't happen here.

---

***ALWAYS REMEMBER THIS:*** By giving someone physical access to the machine, or access in general, you are going to put your files and data at risk.  This is a widely-accepted fact in the IT Security world, and one that continues to hold true.  Giving your friends access to your computer will always put your data at risk, so either give them their own system to mess around with, or just don't give them access to *your* machine.

---

**Just a note on disk encryption**

While disk encryption works well to protect your data from a third party, there's limitations.

1. If the system is on, the disk is already decrypted, so you're at risk.
2. Some systems have *broken* disk encryption approaches.  For example, some Acer systems use your password to only authorize the encryption/decryption and use hard-coded passwords, or use weak encryption that is easily cracked.
3. There are always methods to break into the 'keys', or try to extract them from memory just after a system is turned off but before the RAM data is 'gone' or deteriorated.  (I will not go in depth on these, but these risks *do* exist).
4. ***Physical access to the machine, whether the system is encrypted or not, will always put your data at risk.  Don't give physical access (or remote network access) to people you don't want to potentially give full access to your system to.***

While Disk Encryption doesn't solve these problems, it puts extra layers of headaches for a threat actor.  Someone who is a bad guy might give up if it's encrypted, or they may torture you (queue obligatory [XKCD Security comic strip](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/security.png)).

Therefore, if your system is encrypted, but you're letting other users use it, either they have a password to decrypt, or you're leaving your laptop decrypted so they can SSH in or have physical access.  In both these cases, it's bad.

That said, if your system is not encrypted, then this section has no relevance for you.

Comment: My laptop has an encrypted hard drive. Is allowing others access still a risk?

Comment: @Tim Yes, if the system is powered on and decrypted.  And even when it's off, it's still possible with the right technology, time, and dedication to find decryption keys potentially still stored in RAM.  Disk encryption is *not* 100% protection - there's ways around it, it's more a question of "Is the bad guy willing to actually put that much time and effort into it".  And judging by the OP's question, their system is on and not encrypted (fully, or partially) so the deletion risk is there.

Comment: @Tim To add to Thomas's answer, some laptops have broken disk encryption implementation (if you're relying on hardware FDE). AFAIR Acer laptops don't really use your password for encryption, they use it only to authorize encrypting/decrypting with hardcoded password.

Comment: Data is always at risk if untrusted person has access to a system, encrypted or not

Comment: @ThomasWard To keep friends from deleting or changing the OP's files, isn't it enough to give them separate, limited user accounts, even without changing file permissions? They've been deleting the OP's files, and so might not respect the OP's privacy either, and maybe shouldn't have any access. But if the OP just wants to prevent data loss, is it necessary to change permissions? *If* I'm right that home directories in Ubuntu are always 755 by default, this answer could perhaps be expanded slightly, to mention this simpler option. (I haven't submitted an edit, since you might not want this.)

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes, but this is what I touch upon above to *change* the permissions to only allow that user which owns that directory access to.  (their "Home" directory space just for them).  If privacy is a concern, 755 is too broad; you're right that I should make a note about that though.

Comment: Does `apt-get` _really_ delete files by spawning a shell and invoking `rm` in it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [`apt-get` runs `dpkg`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html#fr4), which [runs scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-maintscripts) that often use `rm`. On my Xenial box, [`cd /var/lib/dpkg/info; grep -P '\brm\b' *inst` outputs 344 lines](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23701758/), of which 333 look like real uses of the `rm` command -- just in *installation* scripts. [`grep -P '\brm\b' *rm`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23701773/) shows even more in removal scripts (to delete config files, not package files).

Answer (score 19):

This may not really be about the `rm` command, since **there are easy ways to delete files without using it**. If the problem is that your friends are unintentionally misusing the `rm` command, then solutions that restrict use of that command specifically or cause it to work in a different way may be of some help. In contrast, if the problem is that your friends are deliberately treating your data in a way you don't want, [then you need to implement actual security measures](https://askubuntu.com/a/865026/22949), and no solution that focuses on the `rm` command itself (or any discrete set of commands) will keep you safe.

### Do you need to control access, or just prevent honest mistakes?

Assuming your friends know you don't want them to delete your files, there are two possibilities:

1. **They could be doing it on purpose.** In this scenario, your friends are deliberately deleting your files, and you cannot even trust them to *try* to comply with your wishes about how they treat your data when they use your computer. The only solution to this problem is [**to use an actual effective security measure**, as Thomas Ward has explained in detail](https://askubuntu.com/a/865026/22949). Often the best such measure is to keep them from using your computer. But making them use their own user accounts can provide some protection.
2. **They could be doing it by mistake.** In this scenario, your friends are extremely accident-prone, and they keep running `rm` commands they wish they hadn't. They want to treat you and your data with respect, but are really bad at doing so in practice because they keep running the wrong command, deleting the wrong file... or something like that. Although it would be nice to believe that this is what's happening, I caution you against assuming that people who keep deleting your data after you've told them to stop are operating without ill will.

   Furthermore, even if their intentions are good, giving them separate user accounts is still the most foolproof way of preventing them from deleting your files, aside from not allowing them to use your computer.

If the situation really is #2 -- your friends are not *trying* to delete your files but just need help not *accidentally* deleting them, and the only way they ever accidentally delete them is through the inadvertent misuse of a small number of commands (like `rm`) that they have particular trouble using correctly -- then [the techniques in Videonauth's](https://askubuntu.com/a/865027/22949) answer may be of some use. But you must understand that they are not security measures, because **the `rm` command is just one of *many* easy ways to delete files**. See below for details.

I recommend you ask yourself, "Is my situation basically the same as if I, rather than the other people who use my computer, were the one using `rm` incorrectly?"

If the answer is *no*, then this is a matter of information security, and you need prevent your friends from using your user account. If the answer is *yes*, then you can use the same approaches you'd use if *you* were the one misusing `rm`:

- *Education.* Your friends need to know what they're doing and how to avoid it.
- *Interface changes.* Without taking away the actual ability to delete files (which requires separate user accounts), you can make it harder to *accidentally* delete files by making it so just running `rm file` by itself, without any further action, won't immediately delete *`file`*. [Videonauth's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/865027/22949) gives one approach to this. In this answer, I present another.

But even if your friends aren't trying to do anything wrong, **you should *still* consider having them use their own separate user accounts**. This will still solve the problem -- the same security measures that protect data from deliberate destruction will protect it from unintentional destruction, too. Even without malicious intent, if someone keeps doing something you don't want them to do, then you cannot trust them to refrain from doing that thing.

### Making `rm` prompt before deletion can help prevent some mistakes.

To help people avoid *accidentally* deleting files with `rm`, you can make `rm` a [shell alias](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) that actually runs `rm -i`. Passing the `-i` flag to `rm` causes it to prompt the user before deleting each file (see [`man rm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/rm.1.html)).

You could do this (for your user account) by adding `alias rm='rm -i'` to your `.bash_aliases` or `.bashrc` file. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias) and [that one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) for details. This will take effect for your newly opened bash shells.

**This provides *no actual security***, and is not foolproof at preventing mistakes either, because:

- They can choose to go ahead with the deletion, when prompted.
- They can bypass the alias in numerous ways, including by running `/bin/rm` or unaliasing it (`unalias rm`).
- [There are many situations where alias expansion does not occur](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases), and in these situations `rm` will not be run with `-i`.
- They can still delete files by using any of the techniques to do so that do not require `rm` (as is the case with [Videonauth's approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/865027/22949) -- see below).
- They can still damage data without deleting any files, such as by overwriting them or otherwise changing their contents (as is also the case with Videonauth's approach).

But if you don't need actual security (see above), then this might be the way to go. By comparison to the approach of preventing your friends from using the system-provided `rm` command:

- Aliasing `rm` to `rm -i` is less effective at preventing mistakes -- until they move on to using some other technique to remove files. At that point, keeping them from using `rm` will be entirely ineffective, even if they're not trying to do anything wrong, since presumably they'll use [`unlink`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/unlink.1.html) (or any of the countless other commands that remove a file) with equal thoughtlessness.
- On the other hand, because alias expansion only occurs in some situations -- roughly speaking, ordinary interactive use of the shell -- your friends might think they're going to be prompted when they're not really prompted (because the command is in a script, for instance, or issued from a different shell). [Videonauth's way](https://askubuntu.com/a/865027/22949) does not have this problem, which is an objective advantage of that method over `alias rm='rm -i'`.
- When a script runs, unless it is written deliberately to use aliases, your aliases are not expanded in it. This means that aliasing `rm` to `rm -i` is very unlikely to break anything. This is an objective advantage of `alias rm='rm -i'`.

### `rm` can't do anything any other perfectly ordinary program couldn't do.

There's really nothing special about `rm`. It is a convenient and self-documenting way to remove files, so restricting access to it risks breaking numerous scripts that rely on it. But it is far from the only way to delete files -- it's just an ordinary program.

A few commands perform some task that a limited (non-[root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser)) user cannot perform without running them. For example, [`sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) lets you run programs as another user, after checking to ensure you're allowed to do so. [`passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/passwd.1.html) edits the database where users' passwords are stored, but only lets you change your own password (unless you're root, in which case you can change anybody's password).

`/usr/bin/sudo` and `/usr/bin/passwd` can do that because they have [the setuid bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) set, as shown by the `s` that appears in the leftmost column when you run `ls -l`:

```
ek@Io:~$ type -a sudo passwd rm
sudo is /usr/bin/sudo
passwd is /usr/bin/passwd
rm is /bin/rm
ek@Io:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/passwd /bin/rm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  60272 Feb 18  2016 /bin/rm
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root  54256 Mar 29  2016 /usr/bin/passwd
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 136808 Aug 17 09:20 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Notice that `/bin/rm` has no `s`: its permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x`, while `/usr/bin/passwd` and `/usr/bin/so` have `-rwsr-xr-x` instead. This makes it so that, no matter who runs `passwd` or `sudo`, it actually runs as the root user, since root is the owner of the executable. (There is also a setgid bit, which, when set, causes executables to run with the group identity of their group owner rather than that of the caller.)

Except for any security vulnerabilities that haven't been discovered yet (or that have been discovered but haven't yet been patched), `sudo` and `passwd` are safe because those utilities are very carefully written so they can only do things that the caller ought to be allowed to do.

`/bin/rm` doesn't work this way. It's not setuid because it doesn't need to be. [Directory permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48580/11938) (and [occasionally file permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)) control what files a user can delete, and they don't need to become root to do it. Just to be perfectly clear, **please do not ever set the setuid bit on `rm`**. The security implications would be disastrous, since then, no matter who runs `rm`, it's as though root ran it! (Utilities like `sudo` and `passwd` check who's really running them and check that something is permitted before doing it; `rm` does no such thing.)

Checking if the setuid (or setgid) bit is set on an executable will tell you if restricting who may run it stands a chance of improving security. Executables that aren't setuid (or setgid) don't have any special status, and anyone can simply copy them and run the copy, bring their own copy from another machine, write a script or program that does the same thing, or use another program to do it.

### Deleting Files Without `rm`

The obvious way to delete a file without `rm` in Ubuntu is to navigate to its location in the graphical file browser (Nautilus, if you're using Unity or GNOME Shell) and delete the file. There are also numerous commands that can be used to delete a file from a terminal, without ever using `rm`.

For example, to remove a file called `foo.txt` in the current directory, the following commands, which work out-of-the-box on Ubuntu and do not require access to `rm`, will achieve that. (Just to be sure, I tested them on [a 16.04 minimal system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) installed with only the standard system utilities, after deleting `/bin/rm`.)

- `unlink foo.txt`
- `busybox rm foo.txt`
- `perl -e 'unlink("foo.txt")'`
- `python3 -c 'import os; os.remove("foo.txt")'` (`python` instead of `python3` in older releases)

That list is, of course, nowhere near complete. No complete list of such commands is possible. Preventing file deletion is one of the things separate user accounts and file and directory permissions exist to achieve. They work very well to prevent it. In contrast, changing the `rm` command (to make it require a password, or in any other way) or restricting access to `rm` don't prevent it at all.

Comment: For actual use, I like GNU `rm`'s `-I` option.  It prompts only for deleting 4 or more files, or for recursive deleting.  So you don't get in the habit of always using `-f`, `\rm` to avoid alias expansion, or typing `y` without reading.  But it will still save you from bad typos where you hit return before you meant to, or your glob matched many files.

Comment: Another interesting way to unlink files: `mv foo.txt  /tmp/.gone`, then reboot, discarding the tmpfs that was backing `/tmp`.  Or just use `mv` to rename multiple files all to the same name, so only the last one is left.  Or just hide files by renaming them with obscure names.  As the first part of this answer points out, if you're trying to defend against malice rather than incompetence, you need to just lock people out of your account.

Answer (score 16):

You can change the permissions on the `/bin/rm` command via the following line which will prevent it being executed without sudo access:

```
sudo chmod 750 /bin/rm
```

*This specifically prevents them from using the `rm` command provided by the system. You should be aware that it does not prevent them from  deleting files in other ways.*

To also prevent them from using the `rmdir` command, which is a common way to delete directories, you can set permissions the same way on its executable path:

```
sudo chmod 750 /bin/rmdir
```

Remind that as well you can only use this commands with sudo rights too.

To change it back if you not like it or other problems occur use `755` for `chmod`

---

As @muru pointed out the above is a very crude solution and might even break system services which are not running on the *root* account. Therefore I add here another option using ACL (access control lists) to do the same and probably much safer ([good to read into as well](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) and you can skip the enabling part because ACL is usually installed on Ubuntu systems nowadays):

So to do the same as above just for the users you want to block would be

```
sudo setfacl -m u:<user-name>:- /bin/rm /bin/rmdir
```

Just replace `<user-name>` with the actual user names you want to prevent using the files.

*As with `chmod`, using `setfacl -m` to prevent specific users from running `rm` and `rmdir` applies to those system-provided commands only. It doesn't keep them from deleting your files and folders in Nautilus or by using other terminal commands.*

Explanation:

- the `-m` flag means to modify the files ACL.
- the first part of the change, the `u` stands for user. It can have the following values `u` for user, `g` for group and `o` for all others
- the middle part `<user-name>` can holt the actual user name or group name according to what you want to change. To set overall changes you leave it empty.
- the third part holds the kind of permissions you want to set. Here in the example we want to set no permissions at all so we put `-`, it can as well contain the following letters `r` for read permissions, `w` for write permissions and `x` for execution.

Comment: It would be better to use ACLs than remove execute permissions for others - any system service that doesn't run as root is now handicapped.

Comment: I agree with you there @muru, but for a short term solution this will work, sadly I don't know much about access lists to add profound information about that to my answer. If you got good reading stuff about this you could drop me a line in chat please.

Comment: `sudo setfacl -m u:<username>:- /bin/rm /bin/rmdir`, IIRC. You can test the ACL with `getfacl /bin/rm /bin/rmdir`

Comment: You remember right. and i just updated my answer.

Comment: The only downside to ACLs like this is it's evil/tricky to maintain these long-term.  And impossible to maintain if there's not individual users on the system for each person *using* the system.  Otherwise, it's a good idea.

Comment: What about `unlink(1)`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yes. There's an effectively unlimited number ways to delete files without `rm`. The solution Videonauth has given here is a possible way to help accident-prone users stop deleting stuff, but it doesn't provide any actual security (which may be okay, if the OP's friends aren't *deliberately* trying to subvert the OP's wishes). Videonauth: I suggest editing this post so it prominently clarifies that it doesn't actually prevent people from deleting files since they don't need the `rm` command to do so. (I'm refraining from editing it myself, in case you don't want to say that.)

Comment: @EliahKagan feel free to edit it in, I'm on my way to hit the sheets right now :). It has been a long day.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Yes, that's the conclusion I wanted the reader to reach ultimately and I could and should have stated it more plainly like you did. (Sorry, about that. I just prepared a presentation for class and am still in engage-audience-with-questions-for-discussion mode. ;-P )

Comment: @Videonauth Understood--and thanks! I've edited to add clarification. I'm not sure if my edit is the best way, or in the best places in the post, to say it--so, as always, please free to edit further.

Comment: Don't forget that Perl, Python, and all the compilers on the system allow the other users to delete files too.  Preventing people from deleting files requires more than just changing the permissions on the `rm` command.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That has already been covered in Eliah's answer :)

Answer (score 8):

This is a very simple answer and will stop someone casually using the rm command without giving a password. *It is not a secure solution* and you should impliment some of the alternate suggestions in the other answers.

However, you could use alias to change the way that the rm command behaves. Try:

`alias rm="sudo -l >/dev/null && rm"`

What this does is when someone enters the rm command, it runs the sudo -l command. This command forces the user to enter their password. If they get it right, it lists their privileges (we discard this output) and exits with status 0, if they get it wrong, it exists with an error.

We then follow the sudo command with a "&&", which exits the following command -- in this case "rm" only if the previous command exits with status 0 -- ie they got the password right.

To make this permanent, include the alias command in `~/.bashrc`.

Note this this is very easily defeated (for example, they could simply type `/bin/rm`.

Answer (score 5):

## Sometimes it's not our friends, we are our own worst enemies

I've written a script to password protect `rm` like the OP requested but also put in edits to prevent you from accidentally deleting:

- /
- /home
- /bin

---

**Edit:** Mar 5 2017 - Change method of checking if running in terminal.

---

### Create the script

Use `gksu gedit /usr/local/bin/rm` and copy in these lines:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

tty -s;
if [ "0" == "$?" ]; then Terminal="Y"; else Terminal="N"; fi

if [ $Terminal == "Y" ] ; then
    # Running from terminal don't allow delete of / or /toplevel directory even if sudo
    for i in ${@:1}
    do
        # Skip options -i -r -v -d 
        if [[ ${i:0:1} != "-" ]] ; then
            # if parameter doesn't begin with '-' it's file or directory, so get real path.
            fullname=$(realpath "$i" 2>&1) # No error messages if file doens't exist
            # We must have at least two `/` in the full path
            levels=$(echo "$fullname" | tr -cd '/' | wc -c)
            if (( $levels == 1 )); then # Test for 1, will be zero when file doesn't exist.
                echo "Attempting to remove top level directory '$fullname'"
                echo "Use 'sudo /bin/rm $@' instead."
                exit 1 # error
            fi
        fi
    done
fi


if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]; then # Only non-root processes enter password (ie "sudo rm ..." is ok)
  if [ $Terminal == "Y" ] ; then
  # Only running from a terminal needs password (ie not cron)

    # log rm usage to /var/log/syslog
    PARENT_COMMAND="$(ps -o comm= $PPID)"   
    logger "$PARENT_COMMAND"" - rm command was used on file: ""$fullname"

    # Get password
    Password=$(zenity --password --title="Password for rm")
    encryptPassword=$(echo -n "$Password" | md5sum)

echo "md5sum: $encryptPassword" # Comment out after viewing one time and updating line below.

    if [[ "$encryptPassword" != "d2c30dc65e59558c852ea30b7338abbe  -" ]]; then
        echo "Invalid password!"
        exit 1
    fi
  fi # non-terminals can't enter password.
fi # root doesn't need to enter password.

# Call REAL rm command with parameters passed to this wrapper sript
/bin/rm "$@"

exit 0
```

Change the password "WE2U" to anything you like and save the file.

### Mark new `rm` script as executable

Flag new `rm` script as executable using:

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rm
```

### How it Works

[image: rm password]

Unless the password is ***WE2U***, the first time you run the script you will get "invalid password" and the encryption key for the password you entered is displayed. Copy and paste this encryption key from the terminal into the script. Then comment out the line with the echo that displayed the encryption key on the terminal.

Because the path `/usr/local/bin` is higher on the list than `/bin` our command `rm` is called. After getting valid password it calls `/bin/rm` to do the real removal.

As Thomas Ward pointed out in another answer, if you were to do a `sudo apt-get install ...` you could be asked for password a thousand times. The script checks if `sudo` is used and doesn't ask for a password. Furthermore if `rm` is called from within GUI application no password is required.

The script calls `logger` to record every time `rm` was manually called using the terminal. Command usage is recorded to `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: You could mask the password by simply including a hashed version of it in the script, and then whenever the user enters a password, it could simply hash it and check it against the hard-coded hash.

Comment: @InitializeSahib hashed password support (encryption) has been added to the script.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative would be to create backup copies of any important files in a directory that non-root users don't have access to. You could use `rsync` or `unison` to synchronize them automatically, just make sure at least one directory in the path to the backup destination is owned by root and mode 700. This would result in having two copies of all the files though. It would be safer to just create a guest user for them to use, except you do need to remember to always lock or log out before giving them the computer or leaving it unattended.

Comment: You might want to point out how to avoid deletion being propagated? And ideally a way to switch that off and on so that when the user is doing something that requires delete to be permanent, it is permanent.

Comment: @ajostergaard My thought was that whenever he gets his computer back from his friends he manually checks that nothing is missing and restores anything that is. But my own preferred tool is unison used in gui interactive mode, which makes it easy to see (and reverse) deletions.

Answer (score 2):

Not the direct answer to the question you're looking for but:

If your friends are deleting your files using the `rm` command then either your friends are either incompetent, jerks, or they're [BOFH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_Operator_From_Hell) wannabes who are trying to teach you not to leave your sessions logged in and unattended. In all cases, the solution is the same: *don't leave your session logged in and unattended*.

This has the advantage of not needing to remember to make special changes to the system whenever you upgrade or get a new system, and also prevents scripts and other things you use that rely on commands behaving as expected from failing in unpredictable ways.

It also has the advantage of stopping "friends" from moving on to the next step. Will you also want to "password protect" the `mv` command if they decide to move your files to /dev/null when they find out that a simple remove doesn't do what they want? When you're in a game like this the only winning move is not to play.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar possibility that I planned for.  On the file server, if the main storage of photos is writable that somone in the family (less technical or by accident) might delete something, accidently drag in the gui which moves the directory, or overwrite an original with an edited version rather than renaming.

I realized that I can protect against that without making the permissions unwritable for everyone else.  ZFS makes periodic snapshots so any accidental deletion or overwriting can be reversed.  (Unlike a backup, a snapshot is lightweight and copy-on-write so it doesn’t multiply your storage usage.)

ZFS is native to FreeBSD. Linux has btrfs which also has snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to password-protect rm, a solution would be to make a wrapper for **rm** that would require root privileges, and ask for a password otherwise. (NOTE: This wrapper may go away when the *coreutils* package is updated or reinstalled.) Also, please note this only secures rm, there are still many, many other ways to delete a file.

---

Open up a terminal and become root. Then run `sudo mv /bin/rm /bin/rmold` to move the old **rm** to another place.

Now run `sudo nano /bin/rm` to create a wrapper.

In Nano, type the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/rmold "$@"
exit "$?"
```

Then hold `CTRL`, and press `X` to exit. Press `Y` when you're prompted, then hit `ENTER` to save the file.

Finally, we need to give this the appropriate permissions:

```
sudo chmod a+x /bin/rm
```

And there you go.

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason, script variables should _always_ be quoted: `$@` => `"$@"`. Here, what you are proposing is a very dangerous version of the original and safe `rm`: what if there is a file named `foo -i -r *` (`-i` added to protect the innocent users)?

Comment: In addition to `"`-quoting `$@` as @xhienne says, I'd urge you to clearly warn readers that this provides no security at all since there are many ways to delete a file. One is to call `rmold`, but there's a multitude of other ways, as discussed in other answers and comments on them. (Even then, this will have the problem that `rm` will *feel* like it deletes files as the current user  -- it's called without `sudo`, and normal `rm` runs as the caller -- but does so as root! If they've recently `sudo`ed, they won't notice they might be deleting system files even if they *know* about the change.)

Answer (score 0):

A very silly workaround for a very silly issue.

If you don't want to `chmod` `rm`, `rmdir`, or `mv` (for `mv filename /dev/null`) or use ACLs, you could create a dummy user with a password nobody but you knows and alias each command to `sudo [user]`, and then make aliases for each command that your friends don't know. This way, when your friends type `rm` the system will prompt them for a password (but guessing the password wrong will log the failed attempt), and you can still just type `rmalias` or whatever you choose to actually delete files.

**Or you could just create a guest account that doesn't have access to your home directory.**

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track. Your answer could be improve by elaborating on how to setup alias, `sudo [user]` and `dummy user`