# Samsung SSD 850 Pro slow speed

Tags: partitioning, ssd, performance

I have recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 on a brand new Samsung SSD 850 Pro. It seems to work fine. However the read and write speeds are roughly half of advertised

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   9012 MB in  2.00 seconds = 4507.79 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 808 MB in  3.01 seconds = 268.75 MB/sec
```

AHCI is enabled in BIOS and the system boots on UEFI.

The SSD has 6 partitions

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8AAFFE6D-A829-46B5-B46F-ED4F7432F5B5

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    485375    483328  236M EFI System
/dev/sda2     485376  39544831  39059456 18.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   39544832 117671935  78127104 37.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  117671936 133294079  15622144  7.5G Linux swap
/dev/sda5  133294080 259123199 125829120   60G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  259123200 468838399 209715200  100G Linux filesystem
```

Is there a problem in my setup? What might be the reason for lower than expected speeds? Any input is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Forgot to mention that the SSD is mounted on a 2010 Dell Latitude E6410 which I have just learned that has a SATA II connector. It seems then, the speeds I am getting are reasonable.

Thanks everyone for their comments and answers!

Comment: What is your motherboard model?  What type of connector are you connecting it to?  SATA 2 or SATA 3?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right command to answer your question but    sudo dmesg | grep -i sata | grep 'link up'  shows                                                          [    1.813900] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.814236] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)

Comment: 3.0 Gbps is a SATA 2 connection.  That will max at 300MB/s which is correct for your speeds.  If you saw 6.0 Gbps that would be SATA 3 and it would max at 600 MB/s.  I would check your motherboard to see if it has any SATA 3 connectors on it at all.

Comment: You might be interested in this question where the author has the same SSD as you and invested many hours addressing speed issues: https://askubuntu.com/questions/881255/slow-boot-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-samsung-850-pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SATA II channel (3 Gbps) vs. SATA III channel (6 Gbps)

Looking at your timings it is similar to my `/dev/sdc`

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 Timing cached reads:   20494 MB in  2.00 seconds = 10255.92 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 812 MB in  3.00 seconds = 270.63 MB/sec
```

What you are hoping for is timings like my `/dev/sda`

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   21598 MB in  2.00 seconds = 10809.23 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1566 MB in  3.00 seconds = 521.44 MB/sec
```

The explanation can be found using `dmesg | grep SATA`

```
$ dmesg | grep SATA
[    1.177247] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
[    1.202732] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf1618000 port 0xf1618100 irq 27
[    1.202735] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf1618000 port 0xf1618180 irq 27
[    1.202736] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf1618000 port 0xf1618200 irq 27
[    1.202739] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf1618000 port 0xf1618280 irq 27
[    1.521294] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    1.521318] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.521337] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.521356] ata4: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
```

Both `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdc` are SATA III SSD's but `sda` is on a 6 Gbps bus (ata1) and `sdc` is on a 3 Gbps bus.

## Comparison to SATA II 500GB HDD on a SATA III Channel

For comparison sakes here are the results of a 5400 rpm SATA II 500 GB HDD running on a SATA III (6 Gbps) channel:

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 Timing cached reads:   20632 MB in  2.00 seconds = 10325.32 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 340 MB in  3.02 seconds = 112.76 MB/sec
```

## Summary

This is a laptop and only has two SATA channels:

- ata1 and ata2 are SATA III channels (6 Gbps)
- ata3 and ata4 are SATA II channels (3 Gbps)

Linux/Ubuntu matches the device's SATA ability and channel's SATA ability to the lowest common denominator:

- ata1 has a 240GB SSD SATA III attached.
- ata2 has a 500GB HDD SATA II attached to SATA III channel.
- ata3 has a 120GB PCIe half-height SSD SATA III attached to SATA II channel.
- ata4 has a CD/DVD optical drive SATA I (1.5 Gbps) attached to SATA II channel.