# VS Code takes very long to open

Tags: 18.10, visual-studio-code

If is use `code .` in terminal or just open vs code from menu, it is taking almost 15 to 20 seconds to open. I'm using **Ubuntu 18.10** in *Ideapad 100* with i3 5005u 8GB ram and SAMSUNG 850 evo 250GB ssd.

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to ensure you Samsung 850 Evo is working up to capacity.

Use `hdparm` command to reveal speed:

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/nvme0n1p1

/dev/nvme0n1p1:
 Timing cached reads:   22162 MB in  2.00 seconds = 11095.29 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 450 MB in  0.20 seconds = 2279.92 MB/sec
```

If the last line is less than say 1500 MB/sec you might have a problem. There are a number of places you can check to bumping up Samsung 850 EVO speed in Linux. Here is one example: [Samsung SSD 850 Pro slow speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939981/samsung-ssd-850-pro-slow-speed)

Comment: **850 evo** is a SATA 3 ssd, not an nvme drive like you have, and the read speed is as expected (520mb/s)
`/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   7956 MB in  2.00 seconds = 3985.68 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1558 MB in  3.00 seconds = 518.76 MB/sec`

Comment: Another question, do we have to do anything else (like install some drivers) in order to install ubuntu in nvme drive?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 will support nvme just fine, but your BIOS needs to have nvme driver to allow you to boot directly from it.

Comment: @RitamChakraborty Your drive speed is optimal for the SATA III bus. The slow boot issue is caused by something else.