# Why is my start-up is ultra slow?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, startup

I am using Kubuntu 18.04 on my Dell G5 5587. Currently I have a Win10 installed on my SSD, which is in RAID mode and the ubuntu is installed on my HDD. Since Ubuntu can not recognize the RAID SSD I can switch between the Win and Ubuntu from the One-time boot menu.

I tried to figure out what the problem, but could not find any useful info form me.

`systemd-analyze time`:

```
Startup finished in 7.196s (firmware) + 6.311s (loader) + 33.705s (kernel) + 9min 10.475s (userspace) = 9min 57.688s

graphical.target reached after 1min 6.000s in userspace
```

Here is the result of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
    7min 23.369s apt-daily-upgrade.service
     45.488s apt-daily.service
     36.823s systemd-journal-flush.service
     33.693s dev-sda3.device
     33.330s ufw.service
     25.787s systemd-udevd.service
     11.314s mpd.service
     10.723s phpsessionclean.service
      9.636s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
      9.218s mysql.service
      8.353s NetworkManager.service
      7.977s gpu-manager.service
      6.713s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.722s udisks2.service
      4.567s grub-common.service
      3.718s snapd.service
      3.568s networkd-dispatcher.service
      3.347s keyboard-setup.service
      3.211s ModemManager.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      2.941s packagekit.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      2.820s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      2.477s accounts-daemon.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      2.403s systemd-resolved.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      2.286s systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      2.001s apache2.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      1.900s colord.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      1.722s avahi-daemon.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      1.632s mnt-peterkovach-tempus.mount                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      1.624s mnt-peterkovach-bioinfo.mount                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      1.520s mnt-peterkovach-users.mount                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      1.464s systemd-remount-fs.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      1.408s dev-mqueue.mount                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      1.408s sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      1.408s dev-hugepages.mount                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      1.396s thermald.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      1.384s systemd-modules-load.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      1.068s mnt-peterkovach-Data.mount                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      1.068s swapfile.swap                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
       850ms systemd-sysctl.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
       845ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
       828ms wpa_supplicant.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
       730ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       723ms polkit.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       719ms fstrim.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       654ms systemd-random-seed.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
       447ms user@118.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
       440ms rsyslog.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
       410ms systemd-journald.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       384ms boot-efi.mount                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       381ms apparmor.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
       320ms systemd-logind.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
       276ms upower.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       260ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
       212ms setvtrgb.service
       189ms plymouth-read-write.service
       135ms plymouth-quit.service
       116ms snapd.socket
       108ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C783\x2d9061.service
       105ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        99ms rtkit-daemon.service
        89ms snapd.seeded.service
        80ms apport.service
        57ms nvidia-persistenced.service
        33ms user@1000.service
        33ms plymouth-start.service
        31ms systemd-rfkill.service
        12ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         9ms bluetooth.service
         6ms alsa-restore.service
         6ms kerneloops.service
         6ms sddm.service
         5ms pppd-dns.service
         3ms ureadahead-stop.service
         2ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
         2ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         1ms console-setup.service
         1ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
         1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

The result of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
graphical.target @1min 6.000s
└─multi-user.target @1min 6.000s
  └─cups-browsed.service @6min 41.635s
    └─cups.service @6min 41.633s
      └─cups.path @6min 41.631s
        └─sysinit.target @46.162s
          └─systemd-timesyncd.service @43.875s +2.286s
            └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @43.020s +730ms
              └─systemd-journal-flush.service @6.196s +36.823s
                └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.731s +1.464s
                  └─systemd-journald.socket @4.670s
                    └─system.slice @4.670s
                      └─-.slice @4.635s
```

Do you have any suggestions to make it faster?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the solution can be found here: [Ubuntu 16.04 slow boot (apt-daily.service)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service)

The accepted answer says:

This is [Debian bug #844453](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=844453).  `apt-daily.service` shouldn't be run during boot, but only some time afterward.

As a workaround, do `sudo systemctl edit apt-daily.timer` and paste the following text into the editor window:

```
# apt-daily timer configuration override
[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=1d
AccuracySec=1h
RandomizedDelaySec=30min
```

This changes the "timer" that triggers `apt-daily.service` to run at a random time between 15 min and 45 min after boot, and once a day thereafter.  See the [systemd.timer manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.timer.5.html) for additional (not very well written, alas) explanation of what this means.

The second part of the solution can be found here:

- [What is the use of systemd-journal-flush.service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094389/what-is-the-use-of-systemd-journal-flush-service/1095784)

I would have merged in but using phone is awkward.

Comment: Thanks, it got much faster: `systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 7.649s (firmware) + 5.316s (loader) + 8.886s (kernel) + 1min 2.642s (userspace) = 1min 24.495s'
graphical.target reached after 1min 2.624s in userspace`

Comment: Is there a way to make it more faster?

Comment: I've made a note to get additional general tips after work. Also you can google for generic tips. In the meantimeif the original question is answered you can click the grey check mark next to the answer to accept it.

Comment: You could learn a little more from these boot charts: https://askubuntu.com/questions/864277/is-initrd-img-grubs-loading-initial-ramdisk-slowing-down-my-boot

Comment: Today the boot was slow again and the `apt-daily.service` was there again with 2 mins... And as I checked the `systemd-journal-flush.service` remaind almast the same (27 sec). After editing the `journal.conf` the size of the max size remains 4G after reboot.

Comment: It is better (I think) to vacuum your systemd journals monthly in Cron: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012912/systemd-logs-journalctl-are-too-large-and-slow?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answer of WinEunuuchs2Unix install haveged or rng-tools.

It seems you have a Problem with enough entropy too. You can check it directly after login with `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`

Is it rather low (anything below =< 1000) is going to take a long time to generate randomness using /dev/random as apps will block until you have enough entropy. In other words, you will see slow speed while generating keys or while using OpenSSL APIs.

Comment: The output for `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` is 3477. Is it sufficient?

Comment: With low entropy you can move your mouse quickly during boot to create more I think.